# Css media query not working with Samsung S5 on Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am developing a responsive website that displays a video only if you are visiting the site with a PC but it hides it if you are using a mobile phone. I've already set a query that works for most of mobile devices (we can say that it works for every mobile device). I've checked it with an iPhone 5s/6s, a Samsung S4 mini and it works perfectly (using Safari/Internet/Chrome). When I tried with a Samsung S5 it didn't work on Chrome. So the problem is: why the query does not work on Chrome? Maybe it's the size of the Samsung s5 screen? If you want to check the site is http://objectfilms.altervista.org/

The code for mobile devices with smaller screen is this:

```
/* video background nascosto su Mobile phone */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 200px) and (max-device-width : 720px) {
    .video-div { 
        visibility: hide;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

The code that is supposed to work for the Samsung S5 is the following:

```
/* video background nascosto su Samsung S5 */
@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
    .video-div { 
        visibility: hide;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: I've tried using different sizes in the second query but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

The S5 has a resolution of 1080 x 1920, and those are the device pixels, so i think you'd have to query the values of those, like

```
@media screen and (device-width: 1080px) and (device-height: 1920px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { ...
```

...or use the regular pixel values, but not as device pixels:

```
@media screen and (width: 360px) and (height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { ...
```